# Determine underlying integral type of an Enum in C#

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, enums, enumeration

Consider the following enumerations:

```
enum TestSByte:  sbyte  { Value1, Value2, }
enum TestInt16:  short  { Value1, Value2, }
enum TestInt32:  int    { Value1, Value2, }
enum TestInt64:  long   { Value1, Value2, }
enum TestByte:   byte   { Value1, Value2, }
enum TestUInt16: ushort { Value1, Value2, }
enum TestUInt32: uint   { Value1, Value2, }
enum TestUInt64: ulong  { Value1, Value2, }

var types = new Type []
{
    typeof(TestSByte),
    typeof(TestInt16),
    typeof(TestInt32),
    typeof(TestInt64),
    typeof(TestByte),
    typeof(TestUInt16),
    typeof(TestUInt32),
    typeof(TestUInt64),
};

foreach (var type in types)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Type: {0} - {1}.", type.Name, type.BaseType.Name);
}
```

Output:

```
Type: TestSByte - Enum.
Type: TestInt16 - Enum.
Type: TestInt32 - Enum.
Type: TestInt64 - Enum.
Type: TestByte - Enum.
Type: TestUInt16 - Enum.
Type: TestUInt32 - Enum.
Type: TestUInt64 - Enum.
```

What I actually want is to determine what the underlying integral type of each Enum is. I could not find any indication of the same while browsing type definitions in the watch window. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Enum.GetUnderlyingType`:

```
Console.WriteLine("Type: {0} - {1}.", type.Name, Enum.GetUnderlyingType(type).Name);
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying `type.BaseType` and `type.UnderlyingSystemType`. In addition to the static method you mention, I also stumbled upon the instance method `type.GetEnumUnderlyingType()`.

Comment: Wouldn't the underlying type of an `Enum` always be `int`?  And if it isn't, wouldn't you actually want it to be, since every Enum in the Framework seems to be of underlying type `int`?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getunderlyingtype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The underlying type of an `Enum` is `Int32` by default but can be any integral type except `char`. There are many scenarios where types other than `Int32` would be useful (such as unsigned types). In my case, I am writing code as a generic class library so need to handle all possible cases within reason.